# Setup urlManager in Yi2 to work like twitter

Tags: routes, yii2, url-pattern, yii-url-manager

Ho can I set up urlManager patterns in a way that it works like twitter or any other social networks? for example I want to have the following routes:

```
http://www.example.com/[user_id]
http://www.example.com/[user_id]/[mycontroller]/[myaction]
```

- If users write their user_id it goes to their dahboard page.
- If user    write their user_id followed by a controller and action
  name it    proceeds to proper controller action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following two URLs.

The first rule will match any digit and execute the index action of the profile controller. The index action will receive the user ID, so the function will, most likely, look like `public function actionIndex($user_id)`

```
'<user_id:\d+>' => 'profile/index',
```

So `/1` would execute `actionIndex` of the `ProfileController` and passing 1 as the `$user_id`.

The second rule will match any digit followed by two words, separated by a slash of course.

```
'<user_id:\d+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

So `/1/some/something` would execute `actionSomething` in the `SomeController`. And the `actionSomething` would again receive the `$user_id`.